# Passing values using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am new to the ajax concept, but i am having touble setting it up correctly. I am able to to login in the conventional way (using $_POST to another PHP script and then processing), but now I am trying to do it the Ajax way, but I am pretty new to it.
I asked ealier in another question how to accomplish this and they put me in the right direction, but I am still confused as to how I pass the parameters of the form so that my receiver page gets them.
How should I pass the inputs under the inputs :// line in jquery? see below

```
<?php
echo '$("#submitlogin").click(function() {
        inputs =   //grab then inputs of your form #loginform
        //Not sure how to pass the values here? is it with commas and apostrophes?
       $.ajax ({
           url: "loggnow.php",
           data: inputs,
           success: function() {
               $("#login").html("You are now logged in!");
           }
       });
}';
```

Comment: Why are you dumping JS out via echos? You'd be far better off just exiting PHP mode, or at the very leasy using a HEREDOC.

Comment: Yes I will actually move this to a JS library I have.. but just wanted to show all the code in one.. but thank you for the concern

Comment: I suggest you look at this tutorial http://www.queness.com/post/160/create-a-ajax-based-form-submission-with-jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to do the proper data handling in the click handler. First

```
$("#submitlogin").click(function() {

  inputs = {
    "logInUsername" : $('input[name=logInUsername]').val(),
    "logInPassword" : $('input[name=logInPassword]').val()
  };
  // since this is a username and password combo you will probably want to use $.post
  $.ajax ({
    url: "loggnow.php",
    data: inputs,
    success: function() {
      $("#login").html("You are now logged in!");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well, i don't use jQuery, but id imagine the concepts here could be applied.

```
for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++)
{
    if (form.elements[i].name!="")
        request += "&"+form.elements[i].name+"="+encodeURI(form.elements[i].value);
}
```

would create the post string of what is to be sent, then ajax would add the appropriate headers, and send then the ajax could be something as simple as a success and a fail function. You're PHP script can return an error, like 403 instead of 200. But a dump of the response would be better for processing.